# Javascript object not storing data coming from HTML

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-objects, addeventlistener

I am giving two inputs **title** and **status** from the HTML. Javascript is listening to the input and creating one **emptyObj** object to store the values and then appending it to list of objects **objList**.

Here is something happening like if first time I am giving inputs **title: "Node JS"** and **status: "Pending"** the listeners are wokrking fine and I can see them in the **objList**. But next time if I am appending new item to the list the last input vanishes and only the new one is shown.

Inputs --
[HTML Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMG20.png)

HTMML Code --

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=<device-width>, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        #title, #status{
            display: block;
            width: 200px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="divFirst">

    </div>
    <button>You are seeing the pending tasks, please click the button to see completed!</button>
    <input type="text" id="title" placeholder="Please enter the title of the task">
    <input type="text" id="status" placeholder="Please enter the status of the task">
    <script src="DOM.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

javascript code --

```
let objList = [{
    title: "HTML",
    status: "Completed"
},{
    title: "CSS",
    status: "Completed"
},{
    title: "Javascript",
    status: "Pending"
},{
    title: "React Js",
    status: "Pending"
},{
    title: "Mongo DB",
    status: "Pending"
}]
    let emptyObj = {
        title: "",
        status: ""
    }
    document.querySelector('#title').addEventListener('change',function(e){
        emptyObj.title = e.target.value
        console.log(e.target.value)
    })
    document.querySelector('#status').addEventListener('change',function(e){
        emptyObj.status = e.target.value
        console.log(e.target.value)
    })

    objList.push(emptyObj)
```

Now, how can I store the values permanently coming from the Inputs?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: When is `objList.push(emptyObj)` being evaluated? I think that is where your problem lies.

Comment: Your event handlers only change the current value of emptyObj.status/emptyObj.title.  The objList.push operation (and also the create new emptyObj)  is not occurring inside those handlers.

Comment: Another big issue is that there is only one instance of the `emptyObj`.  Adding it to the list does not disconnect that element from itself, and any changes to that element later will effect the element in the array, because they are the same object.

Comment: I am adding the objList.push(emptyObj) at the end of the script.

Comment: Taplar any suggestion how can I encounter this?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using two onchange methods on two different fields, you will always get the second change wrong. as it will change the title and then insert. You should use a button to update your list.

I think you may achieve your requirement by adding the button under the two inputs

```
<button id="updateList" onclick="insertEmpty(emptyObj)">Update List</button>
```

and the following function to DOM.js

```
function insertEmpty(emptyObj)
{
    objList.push(emptyObj)
    console.log(objList);
}
```

remove your

```
objList.push(emptyObj)  // which is currently at the end of your DOM.js
```

Comment: Let me try this

Comment: `document.querySelector('#updateList').addEventListener('click', function (emptyObj)
    {
        emptyObj.title = document.querySelector('#title').value
        emptyObj.status = document.querySelector('#status').value
        // console.log(emptyObj.title)
        // console.log(emptyObj.status)
        objList.push(emptyObj)
    })`